# Is there a way to validate soap action inside the mock feature files in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have a scenario to mock a soap service containing multiple soap actions. The response for every soap action is different. Is there a way to define all these in the same mock feature file?

I am looking for something like below.

When Scenario pathmatches(url);
if either soap action is the operation name or request contains a specific xml tag;
return response 1;
else
return response 2;

Comment: Accepted the answer for previous question. Is there a proposed solution for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to define all these in the same mock feature file?

Yes. Why not.

The selling point of Karate is that you can express any complicated logic as JavaScript expressions. Please refer to this section on conditional logic for ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

The link above is for the http-client, but you can use the same concepts for mocks.  A simple approach I recommend is to duplicate multiple `Scenario:` sections, maybe the `pathMatches()` will be repeated, but it will be very readable.

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/foo') && paramValue('client') != null
  # do something

Scenario: pathMatches('/foo') && requestHeaders['SOAPAction'][0] == 'myaction'
```

You can also create a helper function in the `Background:`

```
Background:
  * def isAction = function(a){ var tmp = requestHeaders['SOAPAction']; return tmp ? tmp[0] == a : null }

Scenario: pathMatches('/foo') && isAction('myaction')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the headerContains() function.

Scenario: pathMatches('/foo') && headerContains('SOAPAction','myaction')

see: https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-netty/#headercontains